# Resolution Limit for Energy Transition Imaging

Tags: microscopy

I understand that when imaging the resolution limit can be given by Ewald's sphere which is due to the maximum amount of momentum that can be transferred.

But how can we come up with a resolution limit for imaging techniques that are based on an excited transition such as florescent imaging where our image is formed from light emitters.

Is this just the resolution limit from the resolving optics or is some expression that includes light diffusion?

Comment: The reciprocal space of a cell's electron density can (in theory) be mapped out to a radius $2d$, where $d=1/\lambda$ is the radius of the Ewald sphere. This concept is typically found in diffractive measurements such as X-ray crystallography, and it's important to note that the word "resolution" in this context actually refers to the ability to reconstruct the molecule's electron density from frequency-domain data, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(electron_density). AFAIK "resolution" for other imaging techniques (like fluorescent imaging) is mostly limited by resolving optics.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Thank you for your comment. I'm still confused on the point of why the electron density is important. Unlike transmission imaging techniques, my understanding is that in florescence, ideally we only want to see the fluorophore protein and thus the specimen can only mess up our measurement. Thats why i'm not sure what to do with the notion of a living cell's electron density. For example, without optics I can't see better then the Ewald sphere because the most a photon can be scattered is 180 degrees.